# Using Mako Templates in Pyramid with Google App Engine

Tags: python, pyramid

With Pyramid and mod_wsgi, to use mako templates you just add this line to development.ini:

```
mako.directories = house:templates
```

Unfortunately, Pyramid in the Google App Engine doesn't have an development.ini file, and I get the following error:

```
File "appengine-monkey/pyramidapp/app/lib/python/pyramid-1.0a9-py2.5.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 74, in renderer_factory
'Mako template used without a ``mako.directories`` setting')
ConfigurationError: Mako template used without a ``mako.directories`` setting
```

Is there any way to pass this environment variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out from the pylons-devel mailing list. Figured I would post the answer here.

The way to do this is pass it to the Configurator as a setting.  So in the `__init__.py` file make the following change:

```
config = Configurator(settings={'mako.directories':['house:templates']})
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I wish more material from pylons-devel made it here to help others.